# Get artist from spotify api using ClientID

Tags: python, spotify

I was using spotify api to get info about a artist with the code below:

```
spotify_artist = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=U2"&type=artist").json()
print(spotify_artist['artists']['items'][0]['genres'])
```

But I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}
```

So I get a spotify clientID but when I use it its not working:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=U2%22&type=artist&ClientID=key
```

(key is the ClientID of the spotify)

But I get the same error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}
```

Do you know why?

I generate a key (cliente id) for the example you can see that dont works properly:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=U2&type=artist&client_id=38a48a7baeae43b8a74a52fc25a85cd0

Comment: Try pasting the code from your example in an IDE that can parse Python code. You're missing a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client id should be sent using **client_id** variable

[Spotify Web API Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/)

Comment: Thanks, now it appears "KeyError: 'artists'".

Comment: Try to remote the %22 sign from your query. Why do you supply that?

Comment: I update the question with a exemple url that seems to be corret but it appears no token provided.

Comment: After reading the documentation it seems that you should use the client_id to perform the authentication. This will give you a token that should be used for all further calls.

Answer (score 1):

According to [spotify developer news](https://developer.spotify.com/news-stories/2017/01/27/removing-unauthenticated-calls-to-the-web-api/) you can't do a call to api without authentication.

YOu need to use requests to authenticat first.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do one-off / ad-hoc request to Spotify API, you can use https://developer.spotify.com/console/ . There you can choose which API to call and just fill in the fields needed (including OAuth Token, where they have `Get Token` button to guide you).